# Does Leo finally come back for Calypso?

Tags: the-heroes-of-olympus

He promised her that he would come back for her.  Did he actually come back?

Leo promised Calypso he would come back for her, but did he actually return to take Calypso home?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

At the end of *The Blood of Olympus* (*The Heroes of Olympus* #5), Leo creates a massive fiery explosion that kills him. However, the Physician's Cure revives him, and he is at Ogygia.

> He opened the access panel in Festus’s neck. The astrolabe was humming away, the crystal pulsing like a neon heart. Leo checked his compass and GPS, and a grin spread across his face.
>   "Festus, good news!" he shouted. "Our navigation readings are *completely* messed up!"
>   Festus said, *Creak?*
>   "Yeah! Descend! Get us below these clouds and maybe –". 
>   The dragon plummeted so fast that the breath was sucked out of Leo’s lungs.
>   They broke through the blanket of white and there, below them, was a single green island in a vast blue sea.
>   Leo whooped so loudly they probably heard him in China. "YEAH! WHO DIED? WHO CAME
>   BACK? WHO’S YOUR FREAKIN’ SUPERSIZED McSHIZZLE NOW, BABY? WOOOOOOOO!"
>   They spiralled towards Ogygia, the warm wind in Leo’s hair. He realized his clothes were in tatters, despite the magic they’d been woven with. His arms were covered in a fine layer of soot, like he’d just died in a massive fire … which, of course, he had.
>   But he couldn’t worry about any of that.

During *The Hidden Oracle* (*The Trials of Apollo* #1), Leo and Calypso arrive at Camp Half-Blood.